# Highlight selected page number in asp:DataPager

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm using a `DataPager` to navigate between pages like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnPreRender="ListView1_PreRender">
        <ItemTemplate>

<a><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Title") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "../books/bookdetails.aspx?Id=" + Eval("Id").ToString() %>' ImageHeight="250" ImageWidth="180"></asp:HyperLink></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            <div class="page-numbers">
                <asp:DataPager ID="lvDataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="6">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField FirstPageText="Back" ShowFirstPageButton="True"
                            ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                        <asp:NumericPagerField />

                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField LastPageText="Forward" ShowLastPageButton="True"
                            ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

For hover effect I'm using this CSS:

```
div.page-numbers a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #1078a5;
        -moz-transition: .2s linear;
        -webkit-transition: .2s ease-out;
        transition: .2s linear;
        border-color: #1078a5;
    }
```

Now how to change the `background-color` for the active page number because I cannot get it to work. I tried something like this:

```
div.page-numbers a:active {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4a7bb8;
    }
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the `:active` pseudo selector.

For example, in hyperlinks, the styles under the `:active` selector will be applied only while the link is being clicked by the user. [Check its definition.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

If you want to style the current page number, first you should set a class for it using the property `CurrentPageLabelCssClass` in `asp:NumericPageField` tag:

Then you can create a CSS rule for that class:

```
.current-page {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4a7bb8;
}
```